# Is MudBlazor Advanced DataGrid's SelectAll checkbox supposed to select all items when a filter is applied?

Tags: datagrid, blazor, filtering, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I've implemented Advanced DataGrid table from MudBlazor: https://mudblazor.com/components/datagrid#advanced-data-grid

When I apply a filter, the tables rows are successfully filtered and I see only rows matching my filter. However, when I then toggle the 'SelectAll' checkbox, items that have been filtered out are also selected (i.e. when I remove the filter, all items in the table, including hidden items have been selected).

As a user, this seems to me like unexpected behavior for Filters & SelectAll checkboxes.

**Is this supposed to be expected behavior for MudBlazor Advanced DataGrid?**

I was also able to reproduce this unexpected behavior on MudBlazor's docs page: https://mudblazor.com/components/datagrid#advanced-data-grid.